# How can i take the advantage of multi-core systems in node using cluster module

Tags: node.js, loader

I read the cluster module from documentation of nodejs according to my understanding we can use this module to take advantage of multi-core systems 
i.e 
i can easily handle the load, means more number of hits on my system on same port but using different cpu's

for ensuring this i am just doing a simple test at my system

here is my code with cluster module

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const servers = [];
const workers = [];
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

  console.log("total no of cpus", numCPUs);
  // Fork workers.
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    workers.push(cluster.fork());
    workers[i].on('listening', (address) => {
        console.log("address", JSON.stringify(address));
    });
   }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });
  } else {
    let app = express();
   // Workers can share any TCP connection
   app.listen(2121, (serverInfo) => {
    console.log("server listening at port 2121", JSON.stringify(serverInfo));
})
app.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.json({success:'success'})
})
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)))
app.get('/loaderio-edc7fc83ca1554036ee53a6807d5efb5', (req, res, next) => { 
    res.sendFile('./loaderio-edc7fc83ca1554036ee53a6807d5efb5.txt') 
})
console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
}
```

and here is the code of without clustering

```
const express = require('express');
let app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.listen(2121 , (serverInfo) => {
console.log("server listening at port 2121", JSON.stringify(serverInfo));
})
app.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
res.json({success:'success'})
})
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)))
app.get('/loaderio-edc7fc83ca1554036ee53a6807d5efb5', (req, res, next) => { 
res.sendFile('./loaderio-edc7fc83ca1554036ee53a6807d5efb5.txt') 
})
```

And I just test it by loader.io i got the test results as below:
result using cluster module

[image]

result using without cluster module

[image]

I am not getting the results as i want 
i got 24 timeouts in using cluster module 
is my approach isn't correct if yes then how can i take the more advantages of multi-core systems in nodejs or is here anything that i missed?.

Comment: In my opinion, using `cluster` module requires a lot of nitty gritty implementation. I recommend looking at PM2 module for this

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running in mode: ` + (process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev'));
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died, restarting!`);
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  app.listen(PORT)
  console.log(`worker ${process.pid} started`);
  console.log('Listening on port ' + PORT);
}
```